# Binding a List<> to a listview in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have the following code:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvDetail" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr>
                            <td><%# Eval("ShpNo")%></td>
                            <td><%# Eval("QtyShp")%></td>
                            <td><%# Eval("NumPallets")%></td>
                        </tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <LayoutTemplate>
                        <table id="tbl1" runat="server">
                            <tr id="tr1" runat="server">
                                <td id="td1" runat="server">ShpNo</td>
                                <td id="td2" runat="server">QtyShp</td>
                                <td id="td3" runat="server">NumPallets</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="ItemPlaceholder" runat="server">  
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </LayoutTemplate>
                </asp:ListView>
```

And in the code behind:

```
List<Visibility> ListVisibility = new List<Visibility>();
    public class Visibility
    {
        public int ShpNo;
        public int QtyShp;
        public int NumPallets;
        public string ETA;            
    }

List<Visibility> items = ListVisibility.FindAll(VisibItem => VisibItem.ETA == Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString());
        lvDetail.DataSource = items;            
        lvDetail.DataBind();
```

but I'm getting the following error when binding:

`<td><%# Eval("ShpNo")%></td>`

`DataBinding: 'AIS.WebVisibility+Visibility' does not contain a property with the name 'ShpNo'.`

What do I need to do in order to get the correct values from the List?

Comment: Well the error message states it can't find, for example, the "ShpNo" *property*. Perhaps the auto-binder doesn't work on public *fields*, as you have. A property looks like: `public int ShpNo { get; set; }`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have fields, instead of properties

```
public class Visibility
{
    public int ShpNo { get; set; }
    public int QtyShp { get; set; }
    public int NumPallets { get; set; }
    public string ETA { get; set; }
}
```

try that