# How to return ListView items for Binding to the ListView

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I want to Populate Windows Services information in Listview using c# in a webform.

I worked on Grideview, where we bind the data source(returned as datatable from DB) with the gridview directly.

I tried similar approach using Listview, where I wanted to return the list of services and bind to Listview on Submit button function.

Problem here is - ListViewItem and ListViewDataItem doesn't take 0 arguments.

```
protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {    
            string machinename = computername.Text.ToString();
            ServiceDetailsListView.DataSource = GetServiceDetails(machinename);
            ServiceDetailsListView.DataBind();

        }

        protected IEnumerable<ListViewItem> GetServiceDetails(string machinename)
        {
            ListViewItem serviceslist = new ListViewItem();
            ServiceController[] services = ServiceController.GetServices(machinename);

            foreach (ServiceController service in services)
            {
                //DataRow dtrow = serviceslist.NewRow();
                //serviceslist.Rows.Add(service);

                ListViewDataItem newListViewItem = new ListViewDataItem();
                newListViewItem.Text = service.ServiceName;
                newListViewItem.SubItems.Add(service.Status.ToString());

                RegistryKey regKey1 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\services\\" + service.ServiceName);
                newListViewItem.SubItems.Add(regKey1.GetValue("ImagePath").ToString());
                newListViewItem.SubItems.Add(regKey1.GetValue("Description").ToString());
                regKey1.Close();

                serviceslist.Items.Add(newListViewItem);

            }

            return serviceslist;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try the following:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/09/06/web-forms-model-binding-part-1-selecting-data-asp-net-vnext-series.aspx
It uses GridView instead of using ListView. GridViews are recommended as they offer more features that you may want to add later on e.g. Paging, Sorting, Filtering etc.
Alternately, you can use a concrete class instead of using a ListViewItem class returning IEnumerable of your new class. Later in the aspx you may using Data binding constructs like #Eval explained here:
[Binding a List<> to a listview in asp.net c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613856/binding-a-list-to-a-listview-in-asp-net-c-sharp)